# Copy html from local html file and place it in a variable for manipulation before appending to DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following problem. I am limited to javascript and jQuery. My file structure looks like this:

```
index.html
assets/ -> templates/ -> template.html
```

I would like to grab the html from template.html for use in a div inside index.html after manipulation.

An example template:

```
<h2 class="question-text js-question-text"> I have a question for you! </h2>
<button class="answer-button js-answer-button" data-button-number="1"></button>
<button class="answer-button js-answer-button" data-button-number="2"></button>
<button class="answer-button js-answer-button" data-button-number="3"></button>
<button class="answer-button js-answer-button" data-button-number="4"></button>
```

I would like to store that template as html in a variable and be able to manipulate the internals (change the question, change the button/answers text, etc.) before placing it on the DOM.

I have been using .load() and appending changes to it afterwards but this requires drawing it twice, which is not ideal.

Additionally, I have tried .get() but cannot make it work as simply as I see it in my head.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I've had similar problems. I think I just went ahead and modified the html after adding it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time at work :-)

use ajax to gather the file contents and the success function to perform your actions. In the end it will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let getView = function(view){

    let html;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'assets/templates/'+view+'.html',
      async: false,
      success: function( data ){
        html = $.parseHTML( data.response );
      }
    });

    return html;

  }
});
```

The variable html will now contain the parsed result of the ajax query. You MIGHT need to tweak it a touch to ensure that its working but that is the general construct. The important thing really there is the async: false. This makes your script wait until you get a response to move on. Otherwise your return value will be blank. Hope that helps!

**Edit:**

To edit an element and set values that you need such as a page title you can use the `.find()` function with `.text()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let getView = function(view){

    let html;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'assets/templates/'+view+'.html',
      async: false,
      success: function( data ){
        html = $.parseHTML( data.response );
      }
    });

    $(html).find('.page-title-selector').text('Your new title!');

    return html;

  }
});
```

Comment: also... when you use this you would do something like var `htmlStuffs = getView('template');` Then you should be cooking with gas. You should be able to query really any html view and build off templates. Its really really useful!

Comment: I will have to give this a try! Thank you, I'll post back once I have!

Comment: If I wanted to use `.find` on the received html to update or change portions of it (Say, each page I load in has a `<h3>` tag and I want to update the text within it based on a condition elsewhere.) before rendering it to the screen, how would I do that?
Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome question! Because you are using `$.parseHTML()` it turns the response which is a string into actual DOM elements that you can manipulate. I will put an edit to the above post showing how you can manipulate the response :-).